# Group elements from an array with php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 118
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-11
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 90.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Room
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
            [NDC_Status] => charged
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 119
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-12
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 90.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Room
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
            [NDC_Status] => charged
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 98
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-19
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 95.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Transfert
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 10
            [NDC_Status] => charged
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 99
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-20
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 95.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Transfert
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 10
            [NDC_Status] => charged
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 100
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-21
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 95.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Transfert
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 10
            [NDC_Status] => charged
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 117
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-22
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 95.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Transfert
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 10
            [NDC_Status] => charged
        )
)
```

The following script will group the elements **when some data elements are equal (rate, item, quantity, ...) and the dates are consecutive**.

In other cases, the items will not be grouped.

```
// We group the elements in to a new array
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $k = $item['NDC_Type'].$item['NDC_Item'];

    if (!isset($result[$k])) {
        $result[$k] = $item;
    } elseif (
        ($i = $result[$k]) && 
        $item['NDC_Rate'] === $i['NDC_Rate'] && 
        $item['NDC_Item'] === $i['NDC_Item'] && 
        $item['NDC_Quantity'] === $i['NDC_Quantity'] &&
        $item['NDC_Taxes'] === $i['NDC_Taxes'] && 
        $item['NDC_TaxesName'] === $i['NDC_TaxesName'] && 
        $item['NDC_Status']=== $i['NDC_Status'] && 
        $item['NDC_Provenance'] === $i['NDC_Provenance'] && 
        $item['NDC_ProvenanceRoomId'] === $i['NDC_ProvenanceRoomId']
    ) {

        $result[$k]['NDC_Id'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Id'];

        $current_dates = explode(',', $result[$k]['NDC_Date']);
        $last_date = end($current_dates);
        if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$last_date} +1 day")) === $item['NDC_Date']) {
            $result[$k]['NDC_Date'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Date'];
        } else {
            $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
        }
    } else {
        $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

If I have only one group, the script groups items as desired.

If I have two or more groups to combine, the first group will be made, but not the other one.

How can I solve my problem ?

---

The expected result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 118,119
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-11,2017-04-12
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 90.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Room
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
            [NDC_Status] => charged
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 98,99,100,117
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-19,2017-04-20,2017-04-21,2017-04-22
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 95.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Transfert
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 10
            [NDC_Status] => charged
        )
)
```

Comment: The result you expect doesn't seem quite right. `118,119` is not a valid literal. Did you mean `Array([0] => 118, [1] => 119)`?

Comment: Is the Data coming from a db? Because then you could group it there already.

Comment: @Jeff, yes. I can't find how to groupe like I need to group. That's why I make it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

It appears that the fields to determine unique come from this line:

```
$k = $item['NDC_Type'].$item['NDC_Item'];
```

And because all 5 elements in the array appear to have equal values in those fields, it attempts to join on those fields. However, the *NDC_Rate* is different in the last three sub-arrays.

#### Solution

One solution is to append the rate to $k:

```
$k = $item['NDC_Type'].$item['NDC_Item'].$item['NDC_Rate'];
```

That way the elements will be grouped by *Type*, *Item* and *Rate*.

See it demonstrated in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/C1CbXV3Y8QtBrNHE).

As [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830296/jeff) mentioned, a simpler solution would be to group the items in the database layer (e.g. if using SQL, use the *GROUP BY* clause - generally similar for various engines like [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html), [sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql), [PostGreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-agg.html), etc.).